# Using a bash script to execute a program on every file in a directory and output to a different directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu

So i'm fairly new to programming, and just started doing research in condensed matter physics. I am trying to write a bash script that will take .txt files within a specific directory and run a FFT program on them and then output the new .txt file into a new directory.

The file format is always xxmT.txt where xx is just the numerical representation of the magnetic field in millitesla, so like 0mT.txt, 5mT.txt ... etc. As you can imagine, there can be hundreds of data files generated and i'm hoping their is a way to expedite the process. Any help is welcome, i'd rather not do this file by file in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "your_input_directory"
for file in *mT.txt; do
    your_FFT_program "$file" > "your_output_directory/$file"
done
```

Comment: You may want to include a test for `[ -f "$file" ]` to prevent calling `your_FFT_program` on any subdirectories contained below the current. (you may also need to further discriminate between *files* and *symlinks* as well, unknown in the current question, but worth mentioning).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I just need to work out a few bugs with my FFT program. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple actions to the find command. In your case:

```
find . -name "*mT.txt" -execdir YOURCOMMAND "{}" ";" -execdir mv "{}" OUTPUTDIR ";"
```

*mv* will only be executed if *YOUCOMMAND* was successful.

Comment: `YOURCOMMAND` must include an *absolute path* or being in your path as it will be executed within each of the subdirectories traversed by `find`.